# python split strings with multi-delimiter and keep those delimiters python--fast way

Tags: python, regex, string

The task is to split a string with muti-delimiters but needs to save the delimiters, i.e., string = u'hey, nice to meet you! I'm Dennis.=)', if the delimiters are ',', '!' and '.', the wanted result is

```
['hey,', 'nice to meet you!', 'I'm Dennis.']
```

Currently what I did is

```
delimiter = ur'(,|!|.)'
temp = re.split(delimiters, source)[:-1]
result = map(unicode.__add__, temp[0::2], temp[1::2])
```

Anyone can help to improve the time efficiency or get any better ideas? I'd appreciate that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split according to the space which exists next to the delimiters.

```
>>> import re
>>> string = u"hey, nice to meet you! I'm Dennis."
>>> re.split(r'(?<=[.,!])\s*', string)
['hey,', 'nice to meet you!', "I'm Dennis."]
```

Comment: presuming there is always a space

Comment: good point! But since the target string is actually Chinese, they won't have a space after any punctuation. Again, for English string, definitely  this is better!